# Gridview inside Repeater not firing Delete Event

Tags: asp.net, gridview, repeater

I have a Repeater that has a gridview in it, which uses an SqlDataSource with a delete command. When I click delete on a given row, it posts back but doesn't fire the delete. Am I forgetting something?

Comment: Could you please provide a peace of source code? There are many reasons why a command will not fire.

Answer (score 2):

Have you set the GridView's [DataKeyNames property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.datakeynames.aspx)? It needs to be set to the item's primary key to uniquely identify the record to modify. If you didn't set it, clicking Delete (or Edit) would cause a postback that doesn't affect anything since a [DataKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datakey.aspx) wasn't associated with each GridView row.

According to the [GridView.DataKeys property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.datakeys.aspx) page:

> When the  DataKeyNames property is
>   set, the  GridView control
>   automatically creates a  DataKey
>   object for each row in the control.
>   The  DataKey object contains the
>   values of the field or fields
>   specified in the  DataKeyNames
>   property.

For example, let's say you're deleting a product item that's identified by a ProductID field.

Your SqlDataSource might look something like this:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="ProductsDataSource" runat="server"
ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:NORTHWNDConnectionString %>"
SelectCommand= "SELECT [ProductID], [ProductName], [UnitPrice] FROM [Products]" 
DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM Products WHERE ProductID = @ProductID">
    <DeleteParameters>
      <asp:Parameter Name="ProductID" />
    </DeleteParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

You would then assign the same "ProductID" primary key to the GridView's DataKeyNames property:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"
        DataKeyNames="ProductID" ...
```

These tutorials may be helpful to you:

- [Inserting, Updating, and Deleting Data with the SqlDataSource](http://www.asp.net/Learn/Data-Access/tutorial-49-cs.aspx)
- [An Overview of Inserting, Updating, and Deleting Data](http://www.asp.net/Learn/Data-Access/tutorial-16-cs.aspx)

Comment: Yes, I successfully use this gridview setup all over my app, and I do specify the DataKeyNames. The only difference between the tens of other gridviews and this one is that it is the child of a repeater.

Answer (score 1):

**First of all,you should add some code for clear questions.Anyone who will try to help you will ask you for some code.**

In my opinion, 
*if you are using `Button,LinkButton,Image` for delete operations may be you forgot using **CommandName**

CommandField which is declared in GridView Columns:

```
<asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" />
```

TemplateField might be:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
   <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDelete" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete"/>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Above declarations will have same result when clicking the link.Check that you have successfully assigned CommandName property.

*Other opinion if you look more in details OnRowDeleting event,if are you setting

```
e.Cancel = true //remove it
```

*Also are you using UpdatePanel between postback operations ??

Answer (score 1):

I just set up a very basic example with no problems. Without posting code (as many others have asked for) there isn't much we can help you with.

Here is the code from my example - nothing tricky here, just bound a string array to a repeater, and bound the gridview to a sqldatasource with the select and delete commands specified.

All I can think is that your datasource doesn't have the delete command / method specified (but you'd get a clear error about this), or that you don't have the DataKeyNames specified in the gridview (but you'd get a clear error about that as well).

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rp" runat="server">
<ItemTemplate>
<p>Row: <%#Container.DataItem%></p>

<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataKeyNames="CroppingID">
    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="CroppingID" HeaderText="CroppingID" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="CroppingID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="CroppingName" HeaderText="CroppingName" SortExpression="CroppingName" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

and the datasource (from an existing database I have set up)

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:sConn %>" DeleteCommand="spD_Cropping" 
    DeleteCommandType="StoredProcedure" SelectCommand="spS_Croppings" 
    SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
    <DeleteParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="CroppingID" Type="Byte" />
    </DeleteParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```